# Migration Error - Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: error, mysql, core, migration, mysql-config

I've upload .zip file and database, and changed database info in local.xml.

Yet, my website is not working.

**Error**

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is
>   disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 291391725209

**var/report**

```
a:4:{i:0;s:105:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)";i:1;s:2973:"#0 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /hsphere/local/home/claudiasousa/domain.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Comment: Is MySQL running? The error "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket" is your hint. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38

Comment: I searched everywhere online. Not sure if it is, how can I check that?
I don't have my.cnf file, neither var/mysql folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you updated your `local.xml` credentials and they are correct and configured domain name in `core_config_data` in db, then it could potentially be a caching issue. You can try to rename your `var` directory in root to `varOFF`. That would tell you that it's a caching or session issue. Hopefully that works.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: It had a different hostname. That's why it wasn't connecting. Thank you!

Comment: That would explain it. Glad to hear it's resolved.